# Root Cause Analysis Using NLP

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining

I am exploring ways of utilizing NLP (not ChatGPT) for root cause of machine failures based on it's past failures, service history etc (all in timestamped text format).

An example is shown below

1/1/2022 : Machine performance was sub-optimal and  overheating was observed.

1/6/2022 : Regular inspection found out that seal was almost worn out. Replaced the seal.

12/11/2022 : Machine failed affecting the production. Seal was broken.

Out of curiosity, tried a similar scenario with ChatGPT and it gives a few convincing answers. :-)

1. *A potential root cause is the machine overheating which causes seal to break and thus the machine fails.*
2. *Seal used is not compatible which can't withstand the heating and thus fails.*

I am interested in identifying the root cause at the machine level. Currently it is done manually looking at the past observations & failures of the machine, which is time consuming.

Any pointers in this regard are highly appreciated. Please let me know if the query is not clear or need further information.